# Excel macro to search multiple urls in one column

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet (Sheet2) that contains 27 columns, first row is the columns headers which are A-Z and NUM totaling 27 cols. Each column has a very long list of restricted urls sorted to the letter of the column, and the last (27th) column is for urls that start with a number. The columns' length is between 300-600 thousand cells.

What I have been looking for was a macro script that will examine all newly added urls in col A Sheet1, to find out whether they exist in Sheet2, resulting in flagging each url with "already exist" or "to be added", something like:

Sheet1

```
Col(A)          Col(B)
badsite1.com    already exist
badsite2.com    already exist
badsite3.com    to be added
badsite4.con    to be added
badsite5.com    already exist
```

Accordingly "to be added" urls will be added to Sheet2 after running another test online for that url.

Amazingly, I found the following script (missed its source) that does exactly what I'm after applying some minor modifications:

```
Sub x()

Dim rFind As Range, sFind As Range, sAddr As String, ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, ms     As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")
Set ms = Sheets("Sheet1")
ms.Range("B2:B" & Rows.Count).ClearContents
Set rng = ms.Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)

For Each sFind In rng
    With ws.UsedRange
        Set rFind = .Find(sFind, .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlPart)
        If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
            sAddr = rFind.Address
            Do
                sFind.Offset(, 1) = rFind.Address
                sFind.Font.Color = -16776961
                Set rFind = .FindNext(rFind)
            Loop While rFind.Address <> sAddr
            sAddr = ""
            Else
            sFind.Offset(, 1) = "No Found"
            sFind.Offset(, 1).Font.Color = -16776961
        End If
    End With
Next
Set ms = Nothing
Set ws = Nothing
Set rng = Nothing
Set rFind = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Running this script is fantastic with a small list of urls (e.g 5-10). With a longer list in Sheet1 col-A and HUGE lists in Sheet2 like mine, this script is a "tortoise", and it took over one hour to examine a list of 167 urls!!

Can this script be modified to be a "rabbit"? :)

Highly appreciating any offered assistance in this regard.

As usual.. thanks in advance.

Comment: From what I understood, I would use the same script but without the `.FindNext` See Section 4 in this link http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/ `EDIT:` If you are still stuck then maybe I can see a sample and then we can take it from there?

Comment: Are you only interested on if its found in sheet1? Or is the last cell address important? Because if the URL exists multiple time this is looping through all and only giving you the last address. From this I can suggest...

Comment: Also do you have formulas?

Comment: In fact, Sheet1 is just to have the new list of urls and to have the result of search process displayed next to each url as per example in question above. So I'm interested in finding out whether a url exists in SHEET2 or not. All urls in sheet2 are unique; zero duplicates. Thus once a url is found, it shall be found once. Sheet2 does not have any formulas, just data, nor does Sheet1. I'm interested in finding out about your "dotted" suggestion glb :). I'm also reading to understand what Siddharth Rout has suggested, thank you both very much for your invaluable inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this - Tested in Excel 2010:

```
Sub x()

Dim rFind As Range, sFind As Range, sAddr As String, ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range, ms As Worksheet, s As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'stop calculation
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")
Set ms = Sheets("Sheet1")
ms.Range("B2:B" & ms.Rows.Count).ClearContents
ms.Range("A2:B" & ms.Rows.Count).Font.Color = 0
Set rng = ms.Range("A2:A" & ms.Cells(ms.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)

For Each sFind In rng
    'get first character of url
    s = Left(sFind, 1)
    'resort to column aa if not a a to z
    If Asc(UCase(s)) < 65 Or Asc(UCase(s)) > 90 Then s = "AA"
    'only look in appropriate column
    Set rFind = ws.Columns(s).Find(sFind, , xlValues, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
        'only look once and save that cell ref
        sFind.Offset(, 1) = rFind.Address
        sFind.Font.Color = -16776961
    Else
        'if not found put default string
        sFind.Offset(, 1) = "No Found"
        sFind.Offset(, 1).Font.Color = -16776961
    End If
Next
Set ms = Nothing
Set ws = Nothing
Set rng = Nothing
Set rFind = Nothing
'enable calculation
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[image]

**Non VBA - Tested on Excel 2010:**

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, INDIRECT("Sheet2!" & IF(OR(CODE(UPPER(LEFT(A2, 1)))<65,
    CODE(UPPER(LEFT(A2, 1)))>90), "AA:AA", LEFT(A2, 1)&":"& LEFT(A2, 1))), 1, FALSE), 
    "Not Found")
```

Comment: I mate a few errors and I've now updated with a few points of note

Comment: Thank you glh for your prompt assistance. In fact, as soon as it is run, it stops with a warning that "Compile error: Sub or function not defined" highlighting "upper" in If code(upper(s)). Any suggestions?

Comment: `Ucase()` i think. I think i was halfway between oracle sql and vba ;)

Comment: Genius glh, it is a real "rabbit" now. Just tested it for a 186 new urls and it took nearly one minute, fabulous. Thank you very much glh for your time and effort spent on such masterpiece.

Comment: Your welcome. Just remember that in the tortoise versus the hare the tortoise **won**!... ;)

Comment: Dear Glh, as I have been using your code for a few days now, I noticed that in Sheet2 columns are searched until row 276759 and values (urls) starting from row or (cell) number 276760 are considered non-existing and accordingly "No Found" is displayed despite they exist as one column may exceed 600,000 entries. Any suggestions? Many thanks..

Comment: Are you using the VBA or non VBA solution?

Comment: I see no reason for it to fail. Are you sure they don't exist?

Comment: I'm using your masterpiece code, which is VBA solution. I would tentatively suggest that you create a testing Sheet2 with 27 columns one of them would have over 300,000 entries and try to test the existence of say 10 entries in that long column that are before entry number 276759, by copying them into Sheet1 and running the code. And then another 10 entries starting from 276760 running the same testing. Your results will reveal if I'm doing something wrong with my worksheet. My best regards and thanking.

Comment: I copied your updated code in the answer, and ran it. Surprisingly, it stopped for a debug at: Set rFind = ws.Range(s & ":" & s).Find(sFind, ws.Range(s & "1"), xlValues, xlParts, xlByRows, xlPrevious). Then I compared it to your code in the picture, which unfortunately I couldn't scroll to the right, and found that that line is different from the one in the answer code. Could you kindly update that controversial line so that I can update mine? Much obliged.

Comment: More than fantastic glh, really fantastic. I am very much obliged. Please accept my best regards.