# Multiple find and grouping of results

Tags: vba, excel

I have two worksheets: 
**Worksheet1** has two columns: A & B.

- ColA contains about 10,000 cells each has sentences of text only. Each cell varies in length up to 50 words.
- ColB contains unique text tags for each cell in ColA.

**Worksheet2** has one column, ColA, which has over 18,000 single words.
What's required is to use every word in ColA of Worksheet2 and find it in ColA of Worksheet1, then retrieve its tag or multiple tags from ColB Worksheet1 grouped for every word searched in third Worksheet3.
Example:
Worksheet1:
`ColA                                 ColB`
 
`Case four adjourned till Jan2011     FG_Suya` 
`Item four modified permanently       SH84-Mindus`
Worksheet2: 
`ColA`
`case`
`four`
`item`
`item four modified`
 
Worksheet3: (after running the requested code)
`ColA                                 ColB`
`Case                                 FG_Suya`
`four                                 FG_Suya`
`_                                    SH84-Mindus`
`item                                 SH84-Mindus`
Code at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16008380/excel-macro-to-search-multiple-urls-in-one-column) is very useful, but it needs to be modified to accommodate for finding multiple instances of a searched word, and grouping of findings per searched word which is to be placed in a third worksheet.

Assistance in this matter is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here sample of how could you start to think about it. The code doesn't use `Range.Find` method, but it uses `Range.Value` as array. So the searching runs faster then looping over `Range.Cells`. If you will test it then I recommend to take small amount of data first :-). HTH.

```
Option Explicit

Private Const TextsSheetName As String = "Worksheet1"
Private Const WordsSheetName As String = "Worksheet2"
Private Const ResultsSheetName As String = "Worksheet3"

Private m_textsSheet As Worksheet
Private m_wordsSheet As Worksheet
Private m_resultsSheet As Worksheet

Private m_texts() As Variant
Private m_words() As Variant

Sub JosefMiller()
    Set m_textsSheet = Worksheets(TextsSheetName)
    Set m_wordsSheet = Worksheets(WordsSheetName)
    Set m_resultsSheet = Worksheets(ResultsSheetName)

    m_texts = m_textsSheet.UsedRange
    m_words = m_wordsSheet.UsedRange

    Dim w As Long
    Dim t As Long
    Dim r As Long
    Dim foundThisWord As Boolean

    For w = LBound(m_words) To UBound(m_words)
        foundThisWord = False
        For t = LBound(m_texts) To UBound(m_texts)
            If (InStr(1, m_texts(t, 1), m_words(w, 1), vbTextCompare) > 0) Then
                r = r + 1
                If Not foundThisWord Then
                    m_resultsSheet.Range("A" & r) = m_words(w, 1)
                Else
                    m_resultsSheet.Range("A" & r) = "_"
                End If
                m_resultsSheet.Range("B" & r) = m_texts(t, 2)
                foundThisWord = True
            End If
        Next t
    Next w
End Sub
```

For the sample data in the WorkSheet3 you should see:

```
case                FG_Suya
four                FG_Suya
_                   SH84-Mindus
item                SH84-Mindus
item four modified  SH84-Mindus
```

Comment: Dee, words of appreciation and thanking will not be enough for such masterpiece. This code works excellent as I tested on both sample and real data. I REALLY AM GRATEFUL. THANK YOU VERY MUCH DEE.

Comment: Dee, is it possible to modify the code to also include phrases of few words in Worksheet2 to be found as they are (as a string) in Workseet2? For example, in my question, phrases like: `adjourned till` and `item four modified` to be found as they are structured only not as words, is it possible please? Many thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dee. I applied your modification, but I got a "type mismatch" error because of the spaces between the searched words. What I'm trying to do is: besides finding single words, can we also find phrases? So in my question, `four` was a word in Workseet2 ColA, if we added `item four modified` to the list in this column, can we find and group its occurrence as it is (not as 3 words) from Worksheet1?

Comment: I have edited the question and the answer as well. WorkSheet2, ColA could have not only words but phrases e.g. 'item four modified'. But it works with this phrase already.

Comment: Spectacular.. marvellous Dee,I really don't know what to say. Thank you very very much for such genius code, thank you.